# Redis, sorted set with pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I currently have the following data structure in Redis

```
client.hmset('user:' + user.id, 'id', user.id, 'user', JSON.stringify(meta));
client.zadd(['user:user_by_created_time', meta.created_time, 'user:' + user.id]);
client.zadd(['user:user_by_age', meta.age, 'user:' + user.id]);
```

I then when to get the first 10 users sorted by age, when there are more than 10, I should be able to pass an `offset` that allows me to use pagination.

What I currently have is the following

```
client.zrangebyscore(['user:user_by_age', '-inf', '+inf'], (err, results) => {
    const multi = client.multi();
    results.forEach(result => {
        multi.hgetall(result);
    });

    multi.exec((err, results) => { ... });
});
```

I'm a bit stuck on how to continue with this, I know it's possible to sort a list, but I can't figure out how to only get 10 users after a specific offset.

I'm using the Node Redis client: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To paginate with sorted sets use [`ZRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrange), not `ZRANGEBYSCORE`. The arguments are the ranks, so to get the first 10 users you use `ZRANGE user:user_by_age 0 9`, to get the next 10 you use `ZRANGE user:user_by_age 10 19`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I overlooked that whilst reading through the documentation, it's working just fine now.

Comment: How can you use ZRANGE for pagination if the sorted set is constantly adding entries?

Comment: @LukePighetti: Could you expand on that? Do you mean that the order of entries can change while someone is in the process of viewing a series of pages? If so, that's an issue inherent in pagination, not something specific to `ZRANGE`. If you wanted to avoid that you could always copy the sorted set and use that snapshot to conduct a series of queries.

Comment: I've settled on ZRANGEBYSCORE using the score as a cursor, `inf` as the upper bound, and it has a handy offset and count to make pagination easy.

Comment: @LukePighetti: OK, but I'm not sure what problem that solves. Real time changes will still cause you to miss entries, etc., and you have the added disadvantage that you can't show the ranking accurately.

Comment: I have just tested this method with realtime changes and it indeed does constrain pagination and it works wonderfully.